Use of the word "any" with imperative verbs. Singular or Plural
I have a grammar question that I'm having a hard time finding a good answer to.
The word "any" is quite a versatile and ambiguous word that could mean one item, multiple items, all the way up to "every" item, depending on the sentence.
I'm specifically curious about the usage of the word with imperative verbs.
Here are some examples:

Take any card that is a club.
Take any card from this deck.
Take any plate that has a cutlery bundle on it so that we can serve ourselves food.

The question is: do these sentences refer to taking a single item, or do they allow for taking multiple items? Does the first sentence mean

Take just one club from the pack, or does it mean
[You may] take all 13 clubs?

I lean towards the former, because I think the singular "card" with the imperative verb tense does tell them to take a card, singular.
EDIT: I believe this question is different because it deals with a more specific context. I found that answer, but it didn't answer my question surrounding the imperative commands.
As I already edited: this question is not a duplicate. The other question did not answer this question directly.

You take a single item from a group of items. Take any question on ELU and answer it. The imperative has nothing to do with it.

Sure, but "any" could mean multiple sometimes. For example "admit any person that has a ticket"

No, any person is a single person. out of all the ones who show up. However, there could be many in that category.

But I do think there is a difference in the imperative and other sentences. "Discard any card" is different from "Any card that falls on the floor is discarded"

No, it's the same thing. A single card from among many.

Hmmm, I'm not sure. Maybe I'm reading it wrong but "any card that falls on the floor is discarded" would pretty clearly mean that every time a card falls on the floor, that card is discarded. Maybe this is where my confusion is

Yes, any card [from the deck] that falls on the floor is discarded. You yourself said it: every time a card etc.

Thanks, Lambie. So it does kind of depend on the meaning, whether implicit or explicit, of the sentence. But it seems undeniable that using "any" with a count noun in the singular means a single item, not many items.

No, if it is used with a singular count noun, it implies more of those in a class or category that are not "in view." Any student caught cheating will be expelled. Any student [from among all the students].

Ok, so to summarize "take any card that meets " mean you take one of them, even if multiple cards meet the critiera?

@user522546 Right. If you meant to allow multiple cards, you would say "Take any cards".

Mathematicians make this distinction with "choose" and "multi-choose". But English defaults to choosing one. But you can take any number of cards that are a club.

It depends on the context.
In the common magician instruction:

Take any card and remember what it is.

it's usually interpreted as singular, equivalent to "Take a card". You would use the plural "cards" if you meant to suggest that multiple cards could be selected.
On the other hand

Remove any card that's torn from the deck.

actually means that every torn card should be removed.
I don't think there's any simple grammatical rule that can be used to determine which case is intended. We determine it from the logic of the situation.
For instance,

Go any time you want.

is ambiguous. If "go" refers to leaving the current place, it's singular because you can only leave once. But if you're talking about going to someplace, you can do this repetitively, so this may be plural. In the latter case, you could make it more explicit by saying "any times", but this will often not be necessary.

Actually, these examples make the problem of the different readings clearer than the answer at the duplicate. Can you add an example which is indeterminate?

I'm not sure what would be a good example. Maybe only intangibles like "idea"? Do you have a suggestion?

This is why I asked about the imperative tense specifically.

I've changed my examples to both be imperative. I don't think it changes the answer.

I think your second example is good, but could mean just removing one, removing every, or removing some, correct? I don't think it necessarily means "every"? In addition, what if you took off the "from the deck?" "Take any card that is torn" would seem to still mean singular. But having "from the deck" indicates kind of a broader indication that they need the deck cleaned up.

As I said, it depends onthe context. If you know that the goals is to have a clean deck of cards, you're obviously expected to remove all the broken cards.

'Go any time you want.' Without context, this could be semelfactive or iterative. // 'We don't need to do any more today, and I know you have to meet Billy. Go any time you want.' // 'You're always welcome to use the holiday cottage. Go any time you want.'

@EdwinAshworth Right, but as I say in my answer, the context clarifies.

Certainly, but doesn't the inherent ambiguity need to be made clear, expounded?

I've added this to the answer. I didn't use your technical terms because I'm not familiar with them myself.

I've seen this previously answered here:
"Any" followed by singular or plural countable nouns?
This is what comes from looking in dictionaries and usage books for grammar information. It's not there, sorry. And that's not how any works. It can modify either plural count nouns or singular mass nouns, which means that any singular noun modified by any is automatically interpreted as a mass noun. That's what happens to idea; it is interpreted as meaning 'thought; mentation'. This is not all that surprising, since, while idea is usually a count noun, it is hard to distinguish an idea from some idea. Ideas are not notably countable. –
John Lawler
CommentedMay 2, 2013 at 0:47

I'm not sure if I agree with this answer "any singular noun modified by any is automatically interpreted as a mass noun." I think it depends on the sentence.

The examples are count nouns.

This is a different question. If it were a duplicate, it would be wrong to answer it, especially with an answer imported from the duplicate.
